# Regex para pegar texto entre <> em python?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

Gostaria de extrair o texto contido entre <> de uma string. De início, construí a seguinte expressão:

```
import re
m=re.search(r'<(.*)>','abevbv envvrhwkv <eiwbv> ebvi <wieunv> ajhbsvhj')
```

A expressão estaria perfeita se não houvessem dois textos entre <>. Nesse caso, terei como retorno:

```
'eiwbv> ebvi <wieunv'
```

Porém eu quero:

```
'eiwbv'
```

Que expressão regular eu teria que usar para obter esse resultado?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A sua RegEx está quase correta, o que deu fez dar errado é que você utilizou um quantifier *greedy* (guloso) no ponto (`.`).

Isso faz com que a regex busque até a ultima ocorrência em que pode ser encaixada, deixando sempre o grupo capturado o maior possível, você deveria ter usando um quantifier *lazy* (preguiçoso), fazendo com que ele sempre pare a captura na primeira ocorrencia do delimitador, no seu caso ">"

Para resolver o seu problema é necessário somente mudar o `*` para `*?`

```
import re
m=re.search(r'<(.*)>','abevbv envvrhwkv <eiwbv> ebvi <wieunv> ajhbsvhj')
```

Answer (score 5):

Coloque uma interrogação após o asterisco, assim:

```
m=re.search(r'<(.*?)>','abevbv envvrhwkv <eiwbv> ebvi <wieunv> ajhbsvhj')

print (m)
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(17, 24), match='<eiwbv>'>
```

[DEMO](https://repl.it/H8cI/1)